# Login Error when using invoke-command as job

Tags: powershell, remoting

When i run PS script (robocopy cmd) on remote machine using invoke-command as job, it throws login error. The account i am running has admin privileges and when i run the same command onthe remote machine, it works fine.

```
Invoke-Command -session $servers -FilePath D:\script.ps1
```

Error 
    2016/10/04 10:39:00 ERROR 64 (0x00000040) Accessing Source Directory 
    The specified network name is no longer available.

My question is what login does the script use when i run it from remote server ?

Comment: What is `$servers`?

Comment: $servers provides list of server names that command is going to run.

Comment: If it's a list of server names, use `-ComputerName` instead of `-Session`

Comment: Tried using -computername and -asjob parameter and session, both of them throw same error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, its a problem with multihop authentication.

http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/powershell-2-0-remoting-guide-part-12-%E2%80%93-using-credssp-for-multi-hop-authentication/

Thanks everyone.